# Convert a binary string, with each char separated by spaces, into a normal C string and print

Tags: c, strings, unit-conversion

This code is a purely for-fun project and it comes from [this challenge](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/intermediate-algorithm-scripting/binary-agents) at freeCodeCamp. This is simply an algorithm challenge which is usually meant for JavaScript, but I decided to perform in C. It will not be used for any production reasons. Please leave any feedback you see fit, with special attention to the loops and data types. I purposely used pointer arithmetic, while, and for loops to explore different approaches to the problems. I also left the printf about number of tokens in there if you'd like to play with it by uncommenting. Also note that I've provided 2 sample binary strings but only one is currently used by default.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

char* binary_agent(char *bin_str);
char bit_string_decode(char *const str);
bool bit_string_is_valid(char *bit_string);
int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "01000001 01110010 01100101 01101110 00100111 01110100 00100000 "
                 "01100010 01101111 01101110 01100110 01101001 01110010 01100101 "
                 "01110011 00100000 01100110 01110101 01101110 00100001 00111111";
    char str2[] = "01001001 00100000 01101100 01101111 01110110 01100101 00100000 01000110 01110010 01100101 01100101 01000011 01101111 "
                  "01100100 01100101 01000011 01100001 01101101 01110000 00100001";
    char *result = binary_agent(str);
    printf("%s\n", result);
    free(result);
    result = NULL;
    return 0;
}

// Purpose: Return an English translated sentence of the passed binary string
// "Chars" must be space-separated
// E.G. binary_agent("01000001 01110010 01100101");
char* binary_agent(char *bin_str)
{
    assert(bin_str);

    size_t count;
    char *token = NULL;
    char *delim = " ";
    count = 0;
    char *ptr = bin_str;

    while((ptr = strchr(ptr, ' ')) != NULL)
    {
        count++;
        ptr++;
    }

    ptr = NULL;
    //printf("Total number of tokens %lu\n", count);

    char *output_buffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*(count+1));
    assert(output_buffer);

    token = strtok(bin_str,delim); // token is null-terminated
    if(!token) return NULL;
    output_buffer[0] = bit_string_decode(token);
    size_t i;
    for(i = 1; token != NULL; ++i) //convert to for loop
    {
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
        if(!token) break;
        output_buffer[i] = bit_string_decode(token);
    }
    return output_buffer;
}

//Parses groups of 8 1s or 0s into a char
char bit_string_decode(char *const str)
{
    assert(str && bit_string_is_valid(str));

    char output = 0;
    size_t i;

    //String needs to be valid for sure here
    for(i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
        switch(str[i])
        {
            case '1':
                output |= 1 << 7-i;
                break;
            case '0':
                break;
        }
    }

    return output;
}
bool bit_string_is_valid(char *bit_string)
{
    assert(bit_string && (strlen(bit_string) == 8));

    while(bit_string && *bit_string != '\0')
    {
        if((*bit_string != '0') && (*bit_string != '1')) return false;
        bit_string++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> OP: Please leave any feedback you see fit, with special attention to the loops and data types.

---

**`char` type**

Although `char` is *signed* or *unsigned*, string functions of the standard library work with the data as if it is was `unsigned char`.

> ... each character shall be interpreted as if it had the type `unsigned char` ... C17dr §7.24.1 3

Also: `char output = 0; ... output |= 1 << 7-i;` is or-ing bits potentially into the sign place.  This really is not a concern, but in general, logical bit manipulation is best done with unsigned types.

`int/unsigned`, in general, is the preferred type to use for efficient/clean code.  Thus using `unsigned/int` rather than `char output` can make for better code.

Putting these ideas together: recommend something more like

```
char bit_string_decode(char *const str) {
    unsigned output = 0;
    size_t i;
    for(i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
        switch(str[i]) {
            case '1':
                output |= 1u << 7-i;  // I prefer unsigned types for bit manipulations
                break;
            case '0':
                break;
        }
    }
    return (char) output;
}
```

**`const`**

`bit_string_decode(char *const str)` does not modify the reference data. Use `const` for greater functional usage, more function clarity and help weak compilers optimize.

```
// bit_string_decode(char *const str)
bit_string_decode(const char *const str)
//                ^---^

// bool bit_string_is_valid(char *bit_string)
bool bit_string_is_valid(const char *bit_string)
```

**Simplifications**

Some alternative ideas to simplify the loop:

```
char bit_string_decode(const char *str) {
    const unsigned char *ustr = (const unsigned char *) str;
    unsigned output = 0;
    while (*(const unsigned char*)ustr) { // cast: see note below
        output <<= 1;
        // Given *str is '0' or '1'
        output |= *ustr++ - '0';
    }
    return (char) output;
}
```

**Allocate to the size of the referenced data, not type**

Code is easier to code right, review and maintain.

```
// char *output_buffer = malloc(sizeof(char)*(count+1));
char *output_buffer = malloc(sizeof *output_buffer *(count+1));
//                                  ^------------^  Referenced data
```

**Consider decoding without destruction**

`binary_agent(char *bin_str)` messes up `bin_str` due to `strtok(bin_str,delim)`.  Use of `strspn(), strcspn(), strchr()` could be used to find the delimiter without changing `bin_str`.  This functional change I find would make for more useful code and greater applicability.

**Missing validation in production**

I would say `strlen(bit_string) == 8` (or equivalent) should always test, not in only in `assert`.  Perhaps as

```
bool bit_string_is_valid(const char *bit_string) {
  if (bit_string == NULL) {
    return false;
  }
  const char *s = bit_string;
  while(* (const unsigned char*)s) {  // cast: see note below
    if((*s != '0') && (*s != '1')) {
      return false;
    }
    s++;
  }
  return (s - bit_string) == 8;
}
```

The cast `(const unsigned char*)` is only useful here for the all but extinct non-2's complement platforms to properly ID the null character.  Drop it, unless code needs that level of portability.

---

**Minor**

**Spacing**

Separate function declarations from functions a bit.

```
bool bit_string_is_valid(char *bit_string);
// add space here
int main(void)
```